# React-native pushing to other class

Tags: react-native, push

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Navigator,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Image
} from 'react-native';

import First from './First';

export default class Home extends Component{
     navSecond(){
    this.props.navigator.push({
      id: 'First',
      title: 'First',
       name: 'First',
       component: First
    })
  }
render(){
    return(
        <View>
        <View style={{height:220,backgroundColor:'#DCDCDC'}}>
            <Image style={{width:120,height:120,top:50,left:120,backgroundColor:'red'}} 
        source={require('./download.png')} />
        </View>
         <View style={{top:30}}>
         <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center'}}>
          <TouchableOpacity style= { styles.views}  onPress={this.navSecond.bind(this)}>
          <Text style={{fontSize:20, textAlign:'center',color:'white',top:20}}> Profile </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
           <TouchableOpacity style= { styles.views1} >
          <Text style={{fontSize:20, textAlign:'center',color:'white',top:20}}> Health Tracker </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>

           <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center'}}>
          <TouchableOpacity style= { styles.views2} >
          <Text style={{fontSize:20, textAlign:'center',color:'white',top:20}}> Medical Care </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
           <TouchableOpacity style= { styles.views3} >
          <Text style={{fontSize:20, textAlign:'center',color:'white',top:20}}> Alerts </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>

           <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center'}}>
          <TouchableOpacity style= { styles.views4} >
          <Text style={{fontSize:20, textAlign:'center',color:'white',top:20}}> Health Topics </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
           <TouchableOpacity style= { styles.views5} >
          <Text style={{fontSize:20, textAlign:'center',color:'white',top:20}}> My Documents </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>

         </View>

        </View>
        );
}
}
```

In this code i need to navigate to First.js using push, but i am not able to do that. By clicking on Profile it should navigate to First.js, here push() is working but that is not navigating to First.js. The above page i set as initial route, then how can i link to all pages?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Navigator,
  TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';

import Home from './Home';

export default class Prof extends Component{

     constructor(){
      super()
   }

    render(){
        return (

             <Navigator
               initialRoute = {{ name: 'Home', title: 'Home' }}
               renderScene = { this.renderScene }
               navigationBar = {
               <Navigator.NavigationBar
                  style = { styles.navigationBar }
                  routeMapper = { NavigationBarRouteMapper } />
            }
         />

            );
    }

 renderScene(route, navigator) {
      if(route.name == 'Home') {
         return (
            <Home
               navigator = {navigator}
               {...route.passProps} 
            />
         )
      }
  }
}


var NavigationBarRouteMapper = {
   LeftButton(route, navigator, index, navState) {
      if(index > 0) {
         return (
         <View>
            <TouchableOpacity
               onPress = {() => { if (index > 0) { navigator.pop() } }}>
               <Text style={ styles.leftButton }>
                  Back
               </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
         )
      }
      else { return null }
   },
   RightButton(route, navigator, index, navState) {
      if (route.openMenu) return (
         <TouchableOpacity
            onPress = { () => route.openMenu() }>
            <Text style = { styles.rightButton }>
               { route.rightText || 'Menu' }
            </Text>
         </TouchableOpacity>
      )
   },
   Title(route, navigator, index, navState) {
      return (
         <Text style = { styles.title }>
            {route.title}
         </Text>
      )
   }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your app grows you'll find out that the Navigator is not enough. So I offer you to use react-native-router-flux. It's works well.

you can simply navigate to any scene and send the data as props.

for example :

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ... } from 'react-native';
import Actions from 'react-native-router-flux';

export default class Example extends Component {
    componentWillMount() {
    
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={()=>{ Actions.media({customData: 'Hello!'}) }}
            ><Text>Navigate to scene Media</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        )
    }   
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Example', () => Example);
```

Navigating to scene `Media`and passing props named `customData` with value of 'Hello'

Comment: Thank you @Ataomega.. i will try with the above code

Comment: @PrasannaKumarKulkarni You're welcome. comment and tag here if you have any further questions regarding RN Router Flux.

Comment: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '_reactnative Router`Flux2.default`.First')  i am getting this error.

Comment: @PrasannaKumarKulkarni you need to share the source code. share it here and ask in another question and tag me.

Comment: what i should write in componentWillMount() function? i missed that

Comment: @PrasannaKumarKulkarni in the example in my answer, it's not necessary. but it depends on your app. componentWIllMount is being executed when component will mount, before rendering anything. that's the first step.

first componentWillMount will happen, then rendering, then componentDidMount